# Java Type Hierarchy in Eclipse shows "Source not found"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am finding Java classes by using ctrl + shift + t, I click on the class I wish to see (example Scanner or Random in java.Utils) the type hierarchy for and it opens a tab that says, "Source not found." I read an answer that said my build path was not correct, but my programs uses these with no problem. Can I fix this so I can start to study type hierarchy or am I doing something wrong? [Page after I click the class in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWVJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE can find the compiled Java *classes*, but not the Java *source*.

You may find a `src.zip` in your JDK folder - try to attach that in Eclipse's JRE/JDK setting.

Comment: @WilliamMcDowell Not entirely sure - it's a long time since I used Eclipse. When you've viewing a class, and Eclipse complains "Source not found" - is there an "Attach source" button there in the editor? That's how it used to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the all jar file content you can install **eclipse Java Decompiler Plugin**

JAD Decomplier plug-in for Eclipse version 3.x and 4.x.

update site: http://feeling.sourceforge.net/update

Steps:

Open Eclipse IDE.

1. Click Help->Install New software Paste above URL and give name as
   JAD.
2. Select the Eclipse Class Decompiler Click on Next and accept
   agreements Install it.
3. Restart Eclipse and check now.